# Running an LDO (AMS1117) at maximum voltage

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I'm wondering about running an LDO regulator, the AMS1117 specifically, at its maximum rated voltage.  The datasheet says 15V.  I've got a project where I truly need 15V.  I want this project to be plugged into the wall with a regular plug, not with a wall-wart or USB, so I'm going to add a Meanwell AC-DC converter with 15V output to the inside of the project.  The project has a little uController board with an AMS1117, 15V max.  Ideally I'd like to just use the 15V to get 3V3 in my project using that board, very low current requirements for the 3V3.  But in everyone's experience, is that maximum on ICs an actual real-world number, or is it only in an ideal lab setup with perfect airflow and controlled at 25C with perfect humidity, etc, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need anyone's experience, you need to read the datasheet. a) is 15V a damage-free voltage, or actually an operating voltage b) how much power do you get when you drop 11.7 V at the current your microcontroller draws? How hot does the datasheet say will your LDO get? c) **L**DO and 11.7V of dropout, um.

Answer (score 1):

The [datasheet](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf) **absolute maximum** input voltage is 15V. In general you do not operate with a nominal input equal to the absolute maximum. You don't even come close to the absolute maximum.

Will a given unit break with 15.5V in? Probably not. Should you do it? **no**. Source a better regulator, dump voltage and power with a Zener or find some other way to keep well within the absolute maximum limits.

[image]

Absolute maximum voltages are (usually) nothing to do with heat directly, they're more to do with sudden catastrophic failure when junctions break down because of a bit of a glitch on the power supply or whatever.

Comment: Yes, fair enough on all points.  It is the absolute maximum, so in the end, just get a part more suited to the task.